# Change loaded source color

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I've a rect created on canvas. After creating, i change the background pattern with test.svg. It's working, there's no problem here. What i want to do is to change the color of background pattern. Inside svg, i have a dot. i only want to change the dot color inside svg but not like "fill:color", just the dot. is this possible? i looked for sth like source color etc. but i couldn't find a solution.

```
var test = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
});


test.fill = new fabric.Pattern({
  source: "test.svg",
  repeat: 'repeat',
});


// add canvas etc here...
// change the color of svg pattern. should be something like test.source.color?
```

Answer (score 0):

I never used `fabric.Pattern()` but I guess it's just an other way to make context.createPattern()`.

For this, you have to first load the svg into an `<img>` tag. This action will block certain capacities over the svg document, like changing the color of inner elements by any external mean.

The only solution, is then to load an other document into an other `<img>` tag (or here into an other `fabric.Pattern()` object), which already has the right color.

One way of avoiding having a lot of svg files with only small changes, is to load once the svg, **not** in an `<img>` tag (it can be directly into the document, with a `DOMParser`, an `<object>` or an `<iframe>`), then edit your document with desired changes, and pass its dataURI version to the `fabric.Pattern` Constructor.

```js
var changeSVGColor = function(color) {
  // update the color
  SVGCircle.setAttribute('fill', color);
  // get the svg data as a string
  var svgData = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);
  // transfrom it to a dataURL
  var svgURL = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(svgData);

  return svgURL;
}

var loadPattern = function(url) {
  fabric.util.loadImage(url, function(img) {
    test.fill = new fabric.Pattern({
      source: img,
      repeat: 'repeat'
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
}

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var test = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  width: 300,
  height: 300,
});
canvas.add(test);

loadPattern(changeSVGColor('blue'));



btn.onclick = function() {
  loadPattern(changeSVGColor('red'));
}
```

```css
#svg {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.js"></script>

<svg id="svg" width="20" height="20">
  <circle id="SVGCircle" cx="10" cy="10" r="10" />
</svg>
<button id="btn">change color</button>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```